# TCP/IP Sockets API Book

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, visual-c++-2005

I have recently bought this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123745403) to get to know some basics about building networking sockets under windows. I'm having problems with compiling the code written in this book for example - in first program it tells you to include

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

I tried these in visual c++ but the compiler return errors; include files not found. has anyone read from the book or know something about it?

Comment: Try compiling using just notepad and gcc. http://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: @bhavinp, what he uses to code doesn't matter as those headers themselves do not exist on a Windows system. He has to include `winsock.h` or `winsock2.h` (depending on needs) as Steve Townsend said.

Comment: so if I include just winsock.h would the book still be useful to work with it?

Comment: yes. The book is teaching BSD sockets, and WinSock and Linux/Unix/POSIX socket APIs are based on the BSD sockets. Most of the function names will be the same - you might run into minor platform specific quirks, but nothing that shouldn't be solvable by looking on google. For example, in Winsock you have to call the function `WSAStartup` before utilizing sockets, as it initializes the WinSock DLLs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows you need to include `WinSock2.h` to get access to the Windows Sockets API.  The info in your question looks like it's targeted at Unix system sockets access.

Windows Sockets API (WinSock v2.0) docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  The actual function calls from Unix sockets are mostly also available on Windows but there are also a bunch of Windows-specific functions named `WSA*` that are very helpful in writing efficient Windows-specific sockets code.